# Javascript regex match escaped html character-code

Tags: javascript, regex

My javascript regex is not working properly.

I want to detect A-Z, a-z, 0-9, WHITESPACE and ' _ - .

The problem is: The apostroph is escaped. So its `&#039;`

So `DJ Blubeispiel - I'm Walking In The Darkness.mp3`

becomes `DJ Blubeispiel - I&#039;m Walking In The Darkness.mp3`

How can I detect the escaped apostroph?

---

**Here is my regex:**

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s\(\)\.'_-]{1,}$/;
```

---

The regex is looking for ' and not for `&#039`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
regex = /^([\w\s.-]|&#039;)+$/
```

The `\w` represents any 'word' character, which includes both upper- and lower-case letters, digits, and underscores. The `|` is an alternation, which will first attempt to match the pattern to the right (within the surrounding group), and if it fails, then attempt to match the pattern to the right. The `+` is just a shortened form of `{1,}`.

So this matches any string which consists of one or more instances of word characters, whitespace characters, periods, or hyphens, or the sequence `&#039;`.

Comment: Hello p.s.w.g - thank you for your fast reply. Your regex works fine but only if there no extension. "DJ Blubeispiel - I&#039;m Walking In The Darkness" works but "DJ Blubeispiel - I&#039;m Walking In The Darkness.mp3" is not working :)

Comment: @SteveMuster Initially, I neglected to include the `.` in the character class, but I've since updated it. Please try it now.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works wonderfull. Thank you for making the regex smaller and thank you for your help with the &#039; problem :) | Result: http://puu.sh/7asM5.png